# Can we use DeliveryConfirmationv4 API for international label generation?

Tags: usps

In our system we are using USPS for shipping.

My question is, if we also want to do international shippments and we are using the `DeliveryConfirmationV4` API to generate the label, can we use the same API for International shipping as well. Or do we have to use the `ExpressMailIntl` API?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `ExpressMailIntl` API as there are different requirements in terms of data needed.